# What is the best way to get the parameters in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have code written in files from a website that now is not working, the html code is on pages with php extension, in a folder of a Virtual Host in my PC using Wampserever. `C:\wamp\1VH\PRU1`, when the site was online there was a folder where was a file called image.php. This file was called from other pages inside the site like this: (a little code of a file, C:\wamp\1VH\PRU1\example.php)

```
"<div><img src="https://www.example.com/img/image.php?f=images&amp;folder=foods&amp;type=salads&amp;desc=green&amp;dim=50&amp;id=23" alt="green salad 23"></div>"
```

And the result was that the images was showed correctly.
Now, like I have this project in local, and I HAVE NOT the code of that image.php file I must to write it myself, this way the images will be showed the same way that when the site was online.

When the site was online and I opened an image returned by that image.php file the URL was, following the example, https://example.com/images/foods/salads/green_50/23.png.

Now how the site is only local and I have not that image.php file written because I'm not sure how to write it, the images obviously are not shown.

In C:\wamp\1VH\PRU1\example.php the code of files was changed deleting "https://www.example.com/img/image.php?" for a local path "img/image.php?".

And in the same folder there is another: "img" folder (here must be allocated the image.php file), and "images" folder, inside it /foods/salads/green_50/23.png, 24.png.25.png..............

So I have exactly the same folder architecture that the online site and I changed the code that I could only, for example replacing with jQuery "https://www.example.com/img/image.php?" for "img/image.php?" but which I can not do is replace all the code after the image.php file to obtain a image file.

So I think that the easiest way to can obtain the images normally is creating that IMAGE.PHP file that I have not here in my virtual host.

I'd like to know how to obtain the parameters and return the correct URL in the image.php file.

The image of the DIV EXAMPLE must be C:/wamp/1VH/PRU1/images/foods/salads/green_50/23.png

I have in my PC the correct folders and the images, I only need to write the image.php file.

Note that there are "&" and I must to unite the values of "desc=green&dim=50&" being the result: green_50 (a folder in my PC).

Comment: You can just echo the html: `echo "<div><aimg src='/img/image.aphp?f=images&amp;folder=foods&amp;type=salads&amp;desc=green&amp;dim=50&amp;id=23' alt='green salad 23'></div>" ;` Note the single quotes around html attributes

Comment: For 1 I wouldn't put it in a code snip-it simply adding 4 spaces creates a `code block`

Comment: I don't know if the double quotes are intentional or an "Artifact" of posting a question but this wont work well for you `"<div><img src="`  In generally there are 3 main ways to pass values around on requests (HTTP is stateless), those are `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_SESSION`  In PHP these are called Super Globals,  Global meaning you can access them in any scope.

Comment: sorry, i must to write the image.php file, this file must to obtain the parameters and return a URL of the correct image.   The double quotes are only because i tried to avoid the message: you can not  post images because you have not 10 points lol

Comment: Well, you gotta give a lot more than that then, how are the images stored? Is there a database you need to fetch the image filepath from?

Comment: Seems like you want to generate the url from the src parameters tho...

Comment: If you indented the tags with 4 spaces (in the Question) it would not see them as actual HTML but instead as code.

Comment: the images are stored in folders this way: images/foods/salads/green_50/23.png , 24 . png, 25 .png..........i HAVE HTML pages with DOV elements with src atributes pointing a image.php file, i have all the folders architecture constructed with the imagenes, now i only need write the php code of the image.php file for this retur the correct image to the html's pages

Comment: Why not just write the paths there then?

Comment: In anycase, as I said we have 3 ways to pass values.  For this one you want `$_GET` get, or the request query as it is also known is the part of the url following the `?`  so you have a url `www.example.com/image.php?file=somefile.png` the  `file=somefile.png` can be accessed using `$_GET['file']` on the page `image.php`

Comment: You get this into your code somehow: `/img/image.aphp?f=images&amp;folder=foods&amp;type=salads&amp;desc=green&amp;dim=50&amp;id=23" alt="green salad 23"` Right? Then why not just put the desired result there instead? Why you must use the php to return the url?

Comment: something like this? /n<?php
$f = $_GET['f'];
$folder = $_GET['folder'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$desc = $_GET['desc'];
$dim = $_GET['dim'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

?>

Comment: user3647971, because the code is alredy writen, and i know that only i must to write the fole image.php only. I have all images and folders need it.

Comment: @DanielMartinez See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially just need to parse the $_GET parameters, then do a few checks that the file is found, a real image and then just serve the file by setting the appropriate content type header and then outputting the files contents.

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
// define expected GET parameters
$params = ['f', 'folder', 'type', 'desc', 'dim', 'id'];

// loop over parameters in order to build path: /imagenes/foods/salads/green_50/23.png
$path = null;
foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
    if (isset($_GET[$param])) {
        $path .= ($param == 'dim' ? '_' : '/').basename($_GET[$param]);
        unset($params[$key]);
    }
}
$path .= '.png';

// check all params were passed
if (!empty($params)) {
    die('Invalid request');
}

// check file exists
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    die('File does not exist');
}

// check file is image
if (!getimagesize($path)) {
    die('Invalid image');
}

// all good serve file
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path));

readfile($path);
```

https://3v4l.org/tTALQ

Comment: TY Lawrence! i will probe it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this.

image.php

```
 $id = intval($_GET['id']);
 echo '<div><img src="images/foods/salads/green_50/'.$id.'.png" alt="green salad '.$id.'"></div>';
```

Then you would call this page

```
www.example.com/image.php?id=23
```

So you can see here in the url we have `id=23` in the query part of the url.  And we access this in PHP using `$_GET['id']`.  Pretty simple.  In this case it equals `23` if it was `id=52` it would be that number instead.

Now the `intval` part is very important for security reasons you should never put user input directly into file paths.  I won't get into the details of Directory Transversal attacks.  But if you just allow anything in there that's what you would be vulnerable to.  It's often overlooked, so you wouldn't be the first.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack

Now granted the Server should have user permissions setup properly, but I say why gamble when we can be safe with 1 line of code.

This should get you started.  For the rest of them I would setup a white list like this:

For

```
 folder=foods
```

You would make an array with the permissible values,

```
 $allowedFolders = [
      'food',
      'clothes'
      'kids'
 ];

 etc...
```

Then you would check it like this

```
///set a default
$folder = '';

if(!empty($_GET['folder'])){
    if(in_array($_GET['folder'], $allowedFolders)){
         $folder = $_GET['folder'].'/';
    }else{
        throw new Exception('Invalid value for "folder"');
    }
}

etc...
```

Then at the end you would stitch all the "cleaned" values together.  As I said before a lot of people simply neglect this and just put the stuff right in the path.  But, it's not the right way to do it.

Anyway hope that helps.

Comment: i only need to write the image.php file:                                                    <?php
$f = $_GET['f'];
$folder = $_GET['folder'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$desc = $_GET['desc'];
$dim = $_GET['dim'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $f."/"...........;
?>  until i got the url like this: images/foods/salads/green_50/23.png and that URL will be in the SRC tribute of the IMG element. Am i rigth?

Comment: We'll I don't really know what that means, but hope what I put helps.  Otherwise you may wish to clarify your question

Comment: tvm for your help, this site is the best ever! sorry for my unclariefied question, i only want to know what is the best way to obtain the parameters of that src atribute of the image (now i know that it is $GET), and how to write the PHP code in the image.php file (that does not exist already) to return a URL taking the values of parameters of that SRC.

Comment: @Daniel be sure to call 1 `isset()` and check that all elements exist in the superglobal array.   Check the manual if you dont understand.

Comment: `empty` in my example will do the same thing.  `empty` ignores errors from variables that are not set.  But you can use `isset` if it makes you happy.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php `empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist`

Comment: The difference is that a url with `folder=&id=23` empty but isset. Would/could add an extra `/` in as in   `example.com//23`  With the code I posted, it would throw an exception which may or may not be the way you want to handle it.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

use `$_GET[]`;

```
<?php

$yourParam = $_GET['param_name'];

?>
```

Comment: Please improve this post with a bit more explanation with the intent to educate the OP and future readers.

Comment: OK, must i re wirte it of answer it?

Answer (score 0):

I can obtain the values of parameters in the image.php file tis way:

```
<?php
$f = $_GET['f'];
$folder = $_GET['folder'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$desc = $_GET['desc'];
$dim = $_GET['dim'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

?>
```

But what must i do for the image:
C:/wamp/1VH/PRU1/images/foods/salads/green_50/23.png

can be showed correctly in the DIV with IMG SRC atribute?